# MUI components overlap on window resize

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, jsx

I have a chat component with chat and message input fields.

```
function Chat() {
  const chatBoxStyles = {
    bgcolor: "red",
    height: "70vh",
    mt: "1rem"
  };
  const messageInputStyile = {
    position: "sticky",
    bottom: 3,
    mt: 1,
  };
  return (
    <Container>
      <Box sx={{ ...chatBoxStyles }}></Box>
      <TextField
        sx={{ ...messageInputStyile }}
        variant="outlined"
        margin="normal"
        required
        fullWidth
        id="messageInput"
        name="messageInput"
        autoFocus
      />
    </Container>
  );
}
```

When resizing the window the message input field overlaps with the chat fields.

How can I make it so that instead of overlapping the chat field continues to shrink?

Edit: [Here is how it looks now when resizing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f41UU.png)

Comment: Is it resized vertically?

Comment: yes I added an image for better understanding

Comment: Could you please explain which device has such a height?

Comment: Just a regular monitor. That's just the resized window, not the full screen. I want this component to behave like Facebook's messenger web page a.k.a the input field is always visible, but the messages filed shrink, without overlapping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend considering a specific size for the footer, and for the `<Container>`, calculate the height by subtracting the footer's size. also set the height of the chat box to 100% and enable overflow with auto so that the user can scroll through the chats.

**Example**

```js
import { Box, Container, SxProps, TextField } from "@mui/material";

const footerSize = 64;

function App() {
  const containerStyles: SxProps = {
    height: `calc(100vh - ${footerSize}px)`,
    padding: 1,
  };
  const chatBoxStyles: SxProps = {
    height: "100%",
    bgcolor: "red",
    overflow: "auto",
    width: "100%",
  };
  const messageInputStyles: SxProps = {
    position: "sticky",
    bottom: 3,
    mt: 1,
  };
  const footerStyles: SxProps = { height: footerSize };

  return (
    <Container sx={{ ...containerStyles }}>
      <Box sx={{ ...chatBoxStyles }}>
        {new Array(20).fill(0).map((item) => {
          return (
            <Box p={1} mb={1}>
              <Box width="100%" height={48} bgcolor="#e08c8c" key={item} />
            </Box>
          );
        })}
      </Box>
      <Box sx={{ ...footerStyles }}>
        <TextField
          sx={{ ...messageInputStyles }}
          variant="outlined"
          margin="normal"
          required
          fullWidth
          id="messageInput"
          name="messageInput"
          autoFocus
        />
      </Box>
    </Container>
  );
}
export default App;
```

After making the changes, in my view, if you encounter any issues related to responsive design, consider using `CSS` media queries to fine-tune the details.

[The final image after the changes is available here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y89c9.png)